# Creating a session based site by using Angular and NodeJs

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am developing a site. The back-end is nodejs with express and the front-end is angular (v4). So at the login section how do I manage login session.

Any article or Sample code preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jwt. And then send the token via the http header.

Comment: I am new in nodejs and angular also. So Can you give any sample code. That actually helps me a lot

Comment: You need to generate the token on the server side send it to the client and the client sets it as http header in angular via HttpInterceptor. Then you can verify the token on the server side. https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken